# Install Shield doesn't create new folder

Tags: cmd, windows-10, installshield

I am new to installshield. However, I'm trying to apply the simplest of commands, but ran into an issue.
I have an installation that needs to be installed in c:\program files(x86) (Tried other locations as well). We want to make it automated, so we applied the following command to record the installation.

```
    (Location of the setup)\Setup.exe -r -f1(Full path)\SetupAnswer.iss
```

and run the setup smoothly.
which installed in c:\program files(x86)(Program name) and created an answerfile
Next when I try to run (Location of the setup)\Setup.exe -S -f(Full path)\SetupAnswer.iss On a new PC it doesn't work.
After some testing. I found that if I create the folder name in c:\program files(x86)(Folder name) before I run the command above, it works like a charm.

I can create a short script to create a folder before running the setup command. But it doesn't look "clean". Checking the .ISS file reveals that at the location it wants to create the folder it looks like this -

```
    szDir=(installation path)\(Folder name)
    Result = 1
```

Not sure if this szDir means create or just use the following path.
Let me know if I'm missing something.

Regards,

Nik

Comment: If this is the INSTALLDIR folder then it should be created automatically by the component which installs files under it. 
Try to record it on the new pc (using the -r) and compare the two answer files. Maybe it can shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I was sure though I did a clean installation before... However, I tried it again nevertheless and actually found that the old iss file didn't have a create folder in its sequence. I did as you instructed and it seems to work now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the installation sequence, found it after following yossiz74 advice. There was a missing line due to the folder already existing in c:
Reinstalled it on a clean PC with the record method - Problem solved.